# ReactJS: Transferring Props

Tags: php, reactjs, websocket, autobahn

I'm in the midst of doing up a realtime dashboard application in ReactJS for monitoring sensors. I'm using AutobahnJS + Websockets on PHP to stream data.

This is an abstraction of my dashboard in component view. 
[Abstraction of dashboard in component view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2gm0.png)

**Main.jsx:**

```
class Main extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

componentDidMount() {
    $(document).foundation();

    var that = this;

    var conn = new ab.Session('ws://xx.xxx.xxx.xx', function() {
        conn.subscribe('', function(topic, data) {
            console.log(data);
            that.setState({
               result: data
            });
        });
    }, function() {
        console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
    }, {'skipSubprotocolCheck': true});
}
render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="off-canvas-wrapper">
                <div className="off-canvas-wrapper-inner" data-off-canvas-wrapper>
                    <div className="off-canvas position-right" data-position="right" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>
                        <SensorDetails/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content>
                        <Nav/>

                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="columns medium-12 large 12">
                                {this.props.children}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
};

module.exports = Main;
```

What is the proper way to pass props from Main.jsx to BuildingList.jsx? I have tried replacing:

```
{this.props.children}
```

with

```
<Dashboard data={this.state.result}/>
```

This works but i'm unable to access my links e.g. Account Settings. My react-router is set up as such:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="/dashboard" component={Main} >
      <Route path="/about" component={About} onEnter={requireLogin}/>
      <Route path="/examples" component={Examples} onEnter={requireLogin}/>
      <Route path="/accountSettings" component={AccountSettings} onEnter={requireLogin}/>
      <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
  </Route>
  <Route path="/" component={Login} onEnter={redirectIfLoggedIn}/>
</Router>
```

How would I fix this problem? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to handle this.

One method you can use is to render your children inside of Main.jsx like so. Passing two props to your children (state and updateState).

```
{React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
        state: this.state,
        updateState: (state) => this.setState(state)
    });
}}
```

From your child component you can update the state of Main.jsx by calling this.

```
this.props.updateState({prop: 'value'})
```

I don't think this is the best way of doing things in React. I prefer to take the event approach. I'll usually have something like the following to listen for and update "globally available state".

**Inside of Main.jsx**

```
componentDidMount() {
    App.Event.on('state.update', (state = {}) => this.setState(state));
}
```

`App.Event` is a simple event system that you can invoke by firing events like so.

```
App.Event.fire('state.change', {prop: 'value'});
```

Comment: Thanks Enjijar! I've tried both solutions but neither of them work. For the second solution, I get an "App is not defined" error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, React is designed to pass props from up to down..

It makes Data-Management really hard, because you can have a lot of components which needs the same data.

So its better to use some kind of Flux Architecture, (e.g. Redux)
Or a simpler Data Layer like Mobx.

You should take a look at each because they are very different, but designed to help you with data management, (specially) in React